# RewriteCond doesn't work for specific URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

We have 2 urls (www.floydbariatrics.com and www.floydbariatrics.org)
I'm trying to get all URLs to rewrite to www.floydbariatrics.com

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.floydbariatrics\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.floydbariatrics.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I go to www.floydbariatrics.com or floydbariatrics.com or floydbariatrics.org, the rewrite works.

When I try to access www.floydbariatrics.org, I get:

```
Page Not Found
We cannot locate the page you're looking for. Please check the address and make sure all letters are lowercased with no spaces.
```

I'm completely stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup a VirtualHost for `www.floydbariatrics.org` or do you have `ServerAlias` for it?

Answer (score 0):

On a (shared) hosting server, the web server software needs to be configured individually for each domain, as multiple domains with different content often share the same IP address.

Depending on what control panel software your web host provides (*e.g.* cPanel or Plesk), there may be an option for "Parked Domains", "Redirects", or "Domain Aliases" that could get this working.